# Appropriate file permissions for websites using Git and FTP

Tags: git, apache, ftp, file-permissions, system-administration

What are the appropriate file permissions for a website which can be updated by either Git (e.g. core app files), FTP (e.g. plugins) or upload forms (e.g. images)?

Users involved:

- root
- apache
- ftpuser

Wordpress would be a good example:

FTP updates change the owner to **ftpuser:ftpuser**.

Uploaded images are assigned to the **apache:apache** user by default.

Git updates change everything to **root:root**.

Most people recommend 755 for folders and 644 for files, assuming everything is owned by the same user, which of course is not the case.

I could create an additional group named **web**, assign it to all of the above users and simply `chown -R root:web`, but then I would have to set the default group to **web** for all these users, which is not something I'm comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you could reconfigure Git to use an SSH key owned by **apache:apache**, which would make the file owner **apache:apache**. (Haven't tried this one myself.)
2. Check the available options & configuration for your FTP server -- you might be able to run the FTP server as **apache:apache**, instead of **ftpuser:ftpuser**. If you support other FTP services that require an FTP server running under **ftpuser:ftpuser**, you might still be able to do this by running the (second) **apache:apache** FTP server on a different port.